# Python create decorator preserving function arguments

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a decorator that preserves the arguments of the functions it decorates. The motivation for doing this is to write a decorator that interacts nicely with `pytest.fixtures`.

Suppose we have a function `foo`. It takes a single argument `a`.

```
def foo(a):
    pass
```

If we get the argument spec of foo

```
>>> inspect.getargspec(foo)
ArgSpec(args=['a'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
```

We frequently want to create a decorator where the `wrapper` function passes all of its arguments verbatim to the `wrapped` function. The most obvious way to do this uses `*args` and `**kwargs`.

```
def identity_decorator(wrapped):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper

@identity_decorator
def foo(a):
    pass
```

This, not surprisingly, produces a function with an argument spec reflecting the `*args` and `**kwargs`.

```
>>> inspect.getargspec(foo)
ArgSpec(args=[], varargs='args', keywords='kwargs', defaults=None)
```

Is there a way to either change the argument spec to match the wrapped function or create the function with the right argument spec initially?

Comment: I think in recent Python versions, `functools.wraps` does something to make `inspect.getargspec` and `inspect.signature` report the wrapped function's signature, but it doesn't change the wrapper's real signature. The [`decorator`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator) third-party library provides real signature-preserving decorator functionality through means I've never looked deeply into, probably involving something like bytecode rewriting. I've never used it.

Comment: Maybe check something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3729378/how-can-i-programmatically-change-the-argspec-of-a-function-in-a-python-decorato

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in comments, you can use the [decorator](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/decorator) module or you can use `eval` evil powers to create a lambda function with correct signature:

```
import inspect

def identity_decorator(wrapped):
    argspec = inspect.getargspec(wrapped)
    args = inspect.formatargspec(*argspec)

    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):

        return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)

    func = eval('lambda %s: wrapper%s' % (args.strip('()'), args), locals())

    return func

@identity_decorator
def foo(a):
    pass
```

This is kinda hackish, but it preserves function arguments:

```
>>> inspect.getargspec(foo)
ArgSpec(args=['a'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
```

Answer (score 16):

AFAIK, it is possible only since Python 3.3 with the `Signature` object:

```
def identity_decorator(wrapped):
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
    wrapper.__signature__ = inspect.signature(wrapped)  # the magic is here!
    return wrapper
```

Then, you can do:

```
@identity_decorator
def foo(a):
    pass
```

and finally:

```
>>> inspect.getargspec(foo)
ArgSpec(args=['a'], varargs=None, keywords=None, defaults=None)
```

Comment: This is the most useful answer in Python 3 with the clear use case. Thank you to make my life easier!